# Getting error with HTML code despite that notebook is connected to internet

Tags: html, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I run Jupiter Notebook in Explorer. 
The Internet is on. 
I have installed and import the following packages for the notebook:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import argparse
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
from weasyprint import HTML
```

After manipulations with DF, I am trying to create HTMP template inside the notebook:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Sales Funnel Report - National</h2>
     {{ national_pivot_table }}
</body>
</html>
```

This returns an error:

```
File "<ipython-input-11-7fe4f13eb678>", line 1
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Right, the thing is even with these packages templates have to be just a separate HTML files.